# jQuery custom function not working on master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I have created a custom jQuery function in my web application and it is working fine without master pages, now I have a master page and i have added a reference to my .js file on the Content page and call the custom js method then it gives me error like

> Type error: object function (selector, context){ //the jquery object
>   is actually just the constructor 'enhanced' return new
>   jQuery.fn.init(selector, context, rootjQuery); }has no method
>   'myCustomMethod'

i am calling the custom method like:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#btnTest').click(function () { 
                 try {
                     $.myCustomMethod('testing title!', 'popup.aspx', 600, 400);
                 } catch (e) {
                     alert(e);
                 }
             });
         });
```

my js code is

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myCustomMethod = function (title, src, width, height) {
       // all my code here
}; })(jQuery);
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you created it directly in jQuery library?

Comment: I have created it in a new js file and aadded its ref to my web page, this was working without master page :P

Comment: Has that file being included on all the pages where you intended to run this function?

Comment: yes off-course I added its reference in my web page where I am calling this method (I said that it was working fine when there is no master page)

Answer (score 0):

`$.myCustomMethod('testing title!', 'popup.aspx', 600, 400);`

should be

```
$(this).myCustomMethod('testing title!', 'popup.aspx', 600, 400);
```

Comment: Thanks xdazz, since I have to open the popup on a button click so when I tried the above then it gives me error:
TypeError: Object[object Object] has no method 'myCustomMethod'